# wrap long text in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am querying text from a DB. if the text ends to be too long, I want to be able to wrap the text after, say, 400 characters and display a "..." at the end.
how can it be done?

Comment: Please give us some more details on how you query the database and how you intend to put the results in a html page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you don't do it in your query. You are probably rendering in a proportional font which means 400 characters is never the same size. "..." with a lot of white-space behind it is kinda awkward.

You can query the entire field and cut off using CSS (with limited browser support) with:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have the text in a javascript string:

```
newText = text.length > 400 ? (text.slice(0, 400) + ' ...'):text;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it's:

`SELECT (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(some_column) > 400 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTR(some_column, 1, 400), '...') ELSE some_column END) FROM some_table`

Fill in your own column to be truncated and table, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `o-text-overflow` to Tomas's solution to extend support to Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript and jquery (substring()) may suit your needs.

```
var mystring = somethingFromYourDb
var mystringToDisplay = mystring.substring(0,400);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = mystringToDisplay;
...
```

To display the end of the string, you also have a lot of ways to do it. Opening a new window, using the jquery function "toggle()", ...